# How to generate Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for setting up TLS in GKE

Tags: ssl, https, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a service in GKE and have an Ingress for setting up LTS.
I have tried by my self-signing certificates and I could access to my site through https protocol. It looks good.
Please notice that I have a static IP for Ingress and a domain name for it already.

But now I'm going to create a real-certificates and trying to create a CSR and sending it to CA but I'm so confused after reading those posts:

[Manage TLS Certificates in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#create-a-certificate-signing-request)

[Certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)

I have some questions:

- What's Pod's DNS, Pod's Ip and Service's Ip?
- Do I have to create DNS for pod and service?
- Can I generate the *.csr file from my local PC?
- Can I create a server certificate authentication if I follow the steps in this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls

All I want is to make *.crt and *.key file for setting up https on my service. (I have read some blog posts telling about Let's Encrypt but I don't want to use it).

Thank you for reading.

Comment: you can try using cert-manager which will help you provision SSL certificates for your services https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager

Answer (score 2):

Let's go over each of your questions first:

> What's Pod's DNS, Pod's Ip and Service's Ip?

Within the cluster, each pod has it's own internal IP address and DNS record. Same goes for the services. You can read up on DNS within Kubernetes [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and you can read more about IP addresses [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/).

> Do I have to create DNS for pod and service?

For use within the cluster, that's automatically taken care of for you. If you want to expose a pod/service and have it externally accessible via a DNS record, you'll have to create it somewhere, just like you would for any other server/service/whatever.

> Can I generate the *.csr file from my local PC?
>
> Can I create a server certificate authentication if I follow the steps...

When it comes to GKE and Ingress, handling certificates can be done in two different ways. You can just add a certificate to your project and tell the Ingress controller to use it. [Here in this page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl) you can find a fantastic description on how to do this, and [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/advanced/sslCertificates/list) is the page to create a certificate in the Console. This page also shows you how to do it by using secrets, though I personally prefer the added visibility of using a certificate that's part of my project.

Comment: Is it possible to answer the question "Can I generate the *.csr file from my local PC"?  BTW, if people found GKE ingress and SSL configuration  "effortless", there wouldn't be so many developers asking how to do it. ;-)

Comment: Hey there! Yikes, I didn't mean to sound condescending, sorry! Give me just a second to answer that question of yours.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to submit a CSR to Kubernetes' CA, you'll have to create a certificate via some other method and use the method I described in the post to use said certificate.

Comment: Also, I've changed the wording of the original post so as to not sound condescending, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: One last thing: the certificates generated by the cluster's CA aren't used by the pods when they're exposed, they'll use whatever certificate you configure in the pod's YAML. This means that having the cluster's CA sign a certificate to be used by an exposed service is unnecessary: just generate a certificate elsewhere and tell the pod/service/whatever to use that certificate.

So to answer your question straightforward: you can create a CSR in your PC, but you can't submit that CSR to GKE's master. Submit that CSR to an actual CA, and use the resulting certificate for exposing stuff.